# Google analytics inside if else statement

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm breaking my neck about the tracking code issue inside an if else statement...

I have set an cookie when a visitor accepts some rules. When the cookie not exists you get some text that you should accept. When the cookie does exist then run the google analytics code. All the javascript I placed in a separate file called cookieaccept.js

This is de code in the .js file:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
  var cookie = document.cookie;
  var prefix = name + "=";
  var begin = cookie.indexOf("; " + prefix);

  if (begin == -1) {
    begin = cookie.indexOf(prefix);
    if (begin != 0) return null;
  } else {
    begin += 2;
    var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
    if (end == -1) {
      end = cookie.length;
    }
  }
  return unescape(cookie.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
}

var myCookie = getCookie("cookieaccept");

if (myCookie == null) {
  document.write('To accept click here');
} else {
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
    i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
    i[r] = i[r] || function() {
      (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
    }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
    a = s.createElement(o),
      m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    a.async = 1;
    a.src = g;
    m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
  ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
}
```

But it is still loading the script, or a part of it even if the cookie does not exist and on site i get this error:

[image]

EDIT:

I think the issue is within the else statement in combination with the function:

```
    } else {
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
}
```

Because even if you don't accept the cookie, this code will still be loaded anyway:

```
    ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
    ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
```

So I think I have the define the function in an other way but I have no idea how...

Answer (score 2):

The way google analytics is checking if your analytics.js code is implemented is by accessing your website, downloading the "index" file and checking to see if the analytics.js code is there.

In your case - the code will run only after the user will accept the cookie, and since google-bot will not "accept" the cookie inside your website - it will not be able to see that the code is implemented there.

What you can do is open the "Real Time" section inside google analytics (the first item under "reports" on the left menu inside analytics), access your website, accept the cookie and see if you get data there.
If you got data - basically this means that everything is working correctly.

Comment: I've tested it with the real time view in analytics and you will be only visible if you have accepted it and the cookie is placed on your computer. So that works :) The only thing I don't like is the tag error when you don't accept it, but 99% of the people doesn't have the tag assistant installed so I think I should let that go :)

Comment: Happy to help. You are welcome to voteup/accept the answer if you like to :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is a timing issue, perhaps try

```
  ....
  m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m);
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (ga) {
      ga('create', 'UA-00000000-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
      ga('set', 'anonymizeIp', true);
    }
  },2000);
  })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
}
```

Comment: But the thing I don't understand is how it can get to the code, even if you haven't accepted the cookie... Maybe I need to define the function in another method because I think that's the reason why the "ga" section is loaded anyway.